# K-mean Clustering result in different data set

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have combined different data set to gather to perform a K-mean Clustering. After I get the result, I want to apply the result back into the data one by one. But am not sure how should I do it, any help would be appreciated.

```
#Here is the result 
> VelocityClusters$centers
       [,1]
1 31.587619
2 75.769877
3 48.545961
4  5.252514
```

And here is a code that I wrote and trying to apply the k-mean result back into the single data set, But I know that's isn't seems right.
I been searching online but I can't seem to find the answers.

```
m1_teamA<- m1_teamA %>%
  mutate(Phases = ifelse(mmin %in% 0:5.252514, "walk",
                         ifelse(mmin %in% 5.252515:31.587619,"Jog",
                                ifelse(mmin %in% 31.587620:48.545961, "Run","Sprint"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cbind to concatenate new column data in your data set

dataset_name <- cbind(dataset_name,VelocityClusters$centers)

or, you can use below code

final <- data.frame(dataset_name, VelocityClusters$centers)